# How do I choose a random key from a dictionary, when the key is a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I attempt to use random.choice on my dictionary, which all keys are strings, I get the error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 378, in choice
return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))] KeyError: 0
```

I want the keys to be strings so I can use them in a print statement to say the name of the key.

Comment: _I want the keys to be strings_ So enclose the key value in a `str()` call.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Let `d` be your `dict`. Then you can obtain a list of its keys from `list(d)`.  Then just choose a random key from that list.

Comment: `random.choice(list(mydict.keys()))`  it will work with or without the `.keys()` part

Comment: @TomKarzes  You might want to read my full comment

Comment: Post a running example showing the problem. Simply showing a line in the standard lib is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice` on a dictionary, but you need to pass the keys to it.

```py
random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
```

Or, how some comments are saying, you may be able to do without the `.keys()` part.